# Unexpected function prototype behavior in C

Tags: c, function, function-prototypes

I was studying C from K & R and got confused in **part 4.4 of the book**, when it is referring to scope rules. Before I go any further, let me just post the source file I am working on.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void first(void);

int main(void) {
    printf("In main.\n");

    first();
    second();

    return 0;
}

void first(void) {
    printf("In first.\n");
}

void second(void) {
    printf("In second.\n");
}
```

Now, unless I am more stupid than I imagine, the book gave me the idea **that function prototypes (in the same file as the definition of the function) exist for scoping reasons**. That is, they exist to allow the function to be declared at the top of a compiled file to for the rest of a source file to be notified for the existence of an ***"object"*** if I may so call it, ahead of time.

My issue with the above code is that in an Arch Linux Virtual Machine I am working on with `GCC version 4.7.1` the above file can **NOT** compile and gives the following error: `conflicting types for second`.

However, when the **very same** code is run into my physical machine, sporting **Ubuntu 12.04** with **GCC version 4.6.3** it compiles just fine.

**My question is: *Is this a compiler feature?*** Because if it is not, I am surprised it compiles at all, seeing as there is no function prototype for `second`, `main` (if I have understood it correctly) should not be able to know about `second`'s existence.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "conflicting types" error message happens because most C compilers, upon encountering a function that has not been declared yet, will implicitly declare a prototype for that function returning an int.  So when `second()` is encountered in `main()`, GCC 4.7.1 is inferring the following definition:

```
int second();
```

Then when the compiler reaches the function definition, notices that the inferred prototype's signature does not match the definition's signature, and aborts with an error.

As far as why 4.6.3 successfully compiles this code, the following is a guess.  GCC 4.6.3 may have some bug (or feature, you decide) that allows function implementations to differ from their prototypes by their return type.  Since C allows functions with non-void return types to terminate without returning anything (which makes their return value undefined), this could simply be a case of two sub-optimal things canceling each other out.

(The behavior in 4.6.3 could also be a change in default compiler options between versions, or perhaps you are invoking the compiler with different options.)

Comment: Nice answer bro. But what I don't get is why there is so much different behavior with the same compiler, in two different (but still fairly new) versions.

Comment: Nice, thanx for the compiler clarification, one more fast question: **Since the function prototype is missing, how is this compiling at all? Unless I have misunderstood the book, second() is out of main's scope.**

Comment: Because of the first part of my answer -- using an undeclared function implies a prototype according to the C language, which means that an undeclared function is *automatically* brought into scope with a prototype that is inferred on-the-spot.  **Always compile with `-Wall`** as you would get a compiler warning in both cases.  Compiling with `-Werror` is also recommended (at least for new code) as it will turn all warnings into errors, making sure that you take note of them.  (This prototype-inferring misfeature of C was removed in C99, but GCC still supports it, even in C99 mode.)

Comment: @NlightNFotis: It's a warning, not an error, at least when I try it with gcc-4.7.0.  Please post the full command line and the full gcc output.

Comment: @AdamRosenfield In my machine (and I am looking at it right now) it's an error. However the error is on a Virtual machine that has no gui and guest additions are not installed, so there is no way I can copy paste the compiler output. But if you want me to, I can type it.

Comment: @cdhowie: Note that for an implicitly declared function, the compiler is inferring `int func()` rather than `int func(void)`. The latter wouldn't allow an implicitly declared function to be called with any number of parameters, while the reality is that the compiler allows calling it with any number of parameters.

Comment: @BlagovestBuyukliev That is true, I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: @NlightNFotis: If you want to know why you're getting an error, then yes, please type out the full compiler output.

Comment: @AdamRosenfield `experiment.c.18.6: error: conflicting types for 'second_function'` (second_function is another name for second, I had typed earlier. The rest of the code stays same.) and `experiment.c:9:9: note: previous declaration of 'second_function' was here`

Comment: @NlightNFotis How did you invoke the compiler (which options)?

Comment: @DanielFischer I did not invoke the compiler with any special options. My invoke was as follows: `gcc experiment.c`.

Comment: I would like to point out that the precise reason veterans will insist that you do things properly ("always declare all your functions", "always use -Wall", etc.) is that it's possible - nay, normal - to get inconsistent behavior, such as with two different recent versions of the same compiler. If still not convinced, wait until you've hit *undefined behavior*. With that, the same executable can give you different results depending on the phase of the moon.

Comment: @NlightNFotis seems 4.7 is simply more strict by default then (good news). clang also produces an error `conflicting types for 'second'`, but my gcc-4.6 just a warning.

Comment: @NlightNFotis: Interesting, that must have been a change between 4.7.0 and 4.7.1.  But yes, as Daniel Fischer said, it must be the compiler being more strict by default, which is good.  The C language standard requires a "diagnostic message" if the declarations do not specify compatible types (C99 §6.7/4, §6.7.5.3/15, §5.1.1.3/1), although it doesn't say anywhere that the behavior is undefined AFAICT.